# Java JAR public API between versions

Tags: java, api

I am writing a JAR (actually, AAR, but who cares). I want to verify that I did not remove any public API, nor that they have changed.

Ideally, I would like a tool that will be able to extract public API from a JAR into a file, and then use that output to verify newer versions.

Ideally, output should be a "diff" of modified public APIs.

*Must* be foss/opensource.

Comment: Use maven as a building/management tool. There you can explicitly declare the version you're using, you'd have to check yourself though if newer ones are available

Comment: https://lvc.github.io/japi-compliance-checker/  https://revapi.org/